# Sequelize TypeScript findAll() Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: NaN

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, sequelize.js

I'm currently working on Node.JS Express REST API where TypeScript is used as the language. I'm also working on an ORM library which is "Sequelize" with SQLite as my database. Currently, I'm facing with an issue with "findAll()" function from "Sequelize".

Here's my model which will be used as a table:

```
import { Model } from "sequelize-typescript";
import { DataTypes } from "sequelize";
import { DatabaseConnection } from "../app/database/databaseConnection";

export default class Video extends Model {
  videoId: number = 0;
  name : string = "";
  date : Date = new Date();
  title: string = "";
  description: string = "";
  resolution: string = "";

  readonly createdAt: Date = new Date();
  readonly updatedAt: Date = new Date();
  readonly deletedAt: Date = new Date();
  version : number = 0;
}

Video.initialize({
  videoId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false
  },
  name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
  },
  date: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
  },
  title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
  },
  description: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
  },
  resolution: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true,
  sequelize: DatabaseConnection,
  paranoid: true
});
```

Here's the function that will call the `findAll()` on the model:

```
export const getAll = async (filters? : GetAllVideosFilter) : Promise<Video[]> => {
  const videos = await Video.findAll();
  return videos;
};
```

And I get a "SQLITE_ERROR" from terminal. Here is the error:
[image: SQLITE_ERROR]

I'm unsure with what I'm doing but upon following the documentation from "Sequelize", I cannot find where I am causing an error. Appreciate if someone from the community can help me out.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't pass anything in `Video.findAll();` ? What about passing just `{}`?

Comment: @Anatoly No, but according to the official documentation, I don't need to pass an empty object. Is it really necessary to add it?

Comment: No? that ws just for testing purposes. Even better would be to add simple `where` there and check the generated SQL

Comment: Still the same, I've added `await findAll({where: {}});` and it still generates this SQL statement `'SELECT 'id', 'name', 'date', 'title', 'description', 'resolution', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'deletedAt' FROM 'Videos' AS 'Video' WHERE ('Video'.'deletedAt' IS NULL AND 'Video`.`id' = NaN);'`

Comment: I meant non-empty `where` prop and with something like `where: { id: 1 }`

Comment: I've tried it by adding `return await Video.findAll({where : { id : 1 }})`, but still produces the same error

Comment: And how the generated SQL looks like with `{where : { id : 1 }}`? Please update your post

Comment: Hi @Anatoly, I solved my problem. Do have a look at my answer in this post. Thanks for the help you have given to me. My apologies for responding to your comment late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies for updating this question with an answer late. I got it sorted and found out the issue. Here's the solution.

The code is for my "appRouter.ts". This is where I list my routers and register them to `Router()` libary.

```
import { Router } from "express";
import { VideoController } from "../videoController";

export const appRouter = Router();

//Add your controllers here for Router to identify
appRouter.use('/video', VideoController);
```

This code is for "VideoController.ts". Here is where I created endpoints which does certain database transactions and returns the data. This is where I was missing an endpoint to return the list of `Video`.

```
VideoController.get("/", async (request : Request, response : 
Response<VideoOutput[]>) => {
const videos = await videoRepositoryInstance.getAllVideos();

  if(videos.length >= 1) {
     return response.status(200).json(videos);
  } else {
      return response.status(404).json([]);
  }
});
```

Finally, this code below is where I use the library called "Sequelize" which is a Object Relational Mapper for SQL database transactions and creation of database. This code is also crucial in solving my problem. Here, I was missing the `await` keyword when performing the `findAll()` method which is "Sequelize" method equivalent to performing `SELECT * FROM VIDEO WHERE ...` in SQL query.

```
public async getAllVideos(filters? : GetAllVideosFilter) : Promise<Video[]> {
    return await Video.findAll({
        where: {
            ...filters?.isDeleted && { deletedAt: { [Op.not]: null } }
        },
        ...((filters?.isDeleted || filters?.includedDeleted) && {paranoid: true})
    });
};
```

Huge thanks to all who may have indirectly help me in navigating to the missing details in my solution. I hope this answer helps those who have some similar issues I faced with "Sequelize".